# How do i change the link of the sign up button and login button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you were to click on the My Account page > Login > Login
&
If you were to click on the Register page > Register Now! > Sign up.

It both goes an error page such as  [error page at My account page](https://enza.github.io/action_page.php)
&
[error page at register page](https://dhollenza.github.io/action_page.php?firstname=&lastname=&email=&mobile=&dob=&address=&state=&Category=Race+Categories&remember=on)
respectively.

Any idea how I can change the link of the two buttons to another page?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
```

after checks. here is source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp